# Как настроить авторизацию на сайте через Github?

Tags: php, github, авторизация, oauth

**Ссылка для входа собрал вот такого вида**:

```
if ( $social_config['github'] ) {

        $social_params = array(
            'client_id'     => $social_config['githubid'],
            'redirect_uri'  => $return_domain . "index.php?do=auth-social&provider=github",
            'scope'         => 'user',
            'response_type' => 'code',
            'state' => $_SESSION['state']
            
        );

        $github_url = 'https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize'.'?' . http_build_query($social_params, '', '&amp;');
        $tpl->set( '[github]', "" );
        $tpl->set( '[/github]', "" );
        $tpl->set( '{github_url}', $github_url );

    } else {

        $tpl->set_block( "'\\[github\\](.*?)\\[/github\\]'si", "" );
        $tpl->set( '{github_url}', '' );
    }
```

**Скрипт обработчик собрал вот такого вида**:

```
class AuthViaGithub {

    function get_user( $social_config ) {
        global $config, $lang;

        $params = array(
            'client_id'     => $social_config['yandexid'],
            'client_secret' => $social_config['yandexsecret'],
            'redirect_uri'  => $config['http_home_url'] . "index.php?do=auth-social&provider=github",
            'code' => $_GET['code']

        );

        $token = @json_decode(http_get_contents('https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token' . '?' . http_build_query($params)), true);

        if (isset($token['access_token'])) {

            $params['access_token'] = $token['access_token'];
            $user_agent_git = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

            $user = @json_decode(http_get_contents('https://api.github.com/user' . '?' . http_build_query($params)), true, $user_agent_git);

            if (isset($user['id'])) {

                return array ('sid' => sha1 ('github'.$user['id']), 'nickname' => $user['login'], 'email' => $user['email'], 'avatar' => $user['avatar_url'], 'provider' => 'Github' );

            } else return $lang['social_err_3'];

        } else return $lang['social_err_1'];

    }

}
```

Точно знаю что ошибка начинается либо на этой строчке либо после нее:

```
$token = @json_decode(http_get_contents('https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token' . '?' . http_build_query($params)), true);
```

Подскажите, что делаю не так?

UPD добавил функцию:

```
function http_get_contents( $file, $post_params = false ) {
        
    $data = false;

    if (stripos($file, "http://") !== 0 AND stripos($file, "https://") !== 0) {
        return false;
    }
        
    if( function_exists( 'curl_init' ) ) {
            
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $file );

        if( is_array($post_params) ) {

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post_params));

        }

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5 );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
            
        $data = curl_exec( $ch );
        curl_close( $ch );

        if( $data !== false ) return $data;
        
    } 

    if( preg_match('/1|yes|on|true/i', ini_get('allow_url_fopen')) ) {

        if( is_array($post_params) ) {

            $file .= '?'.http_build_query($post_params);
        }

        $data = @file_get_contents( $file );
            
        if( $data !== false ) return $data;

    }

    return false;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Что делает функция http_get_contents? Я предполагаю, что ошибка в названии этой функции. Наверное вы хотели использовать [file_get_contents](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.file-get-contents.php)?
Также хочу отметить, что использование `@` препятствует выводу ошибок. Пробовали убирать и получать ошибку? Добавьте больше информации про ошибки, если вы их получаете.

Comment: Добавил работу функции: file_get_contents.

Comment: @HotNet Я заметил эти строки: `'client_id'     => $social_config['yandexid'],
            'client_secret' => $social_config['yandexsecret'],`. Там точно Yandex должен быть?